# Mysql query having multiple calculation getting slower

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, view

I have a mysql views which is used for a report. i.e it calculated how many cod orders, prepaid orders, cod order amount, prepaid order amount, grand total and few more calculations in a day and its a join over 5 tables. Its getting too much slower. 
Is there a better way to do such a kind of requirement other then using a view. Or how to make such a kind of requirements faster

```
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(`orders`.`placed_date`,'%Y-%m%-%d 00:00:00') AS `orderdate`,
  DATE_FORMAT(`orders`.`placed_date`,'%Y-%m%-%d') AS `orderdt`,
  COUNT(DISTINCT `orders`.`order_id`) AS `orderscount`,
  SUM(`order_item`.`quantity`) AS `qunty`,
  SUM((`order_item`.`quantity` * `order_item`.`a_unitprice`)) AS `price`,
  COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE `payment_type`.`a_name` WHEN 'COD' THEN `orders`.`order_id` END)) AS `codorderscount`,
  COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE `payment_type`.`a_name` WHEN 'Prepaid' THEN `orders`.`order_id` END)) AS `prepaidorderscount`,
  ROUND(SUM(IF((`payment_type`.`a_name` = 'COD'),ROUND((((((`order_item`.`quantity` * `order_item`.`a_unitprice`) - IFNULL(ABS(`getdisc_function`(`order_item`.`order_item_id`,`order_item`.`quantity`)),0)) + IFNULL(`getgiftwrap_amount_function`(`order_item`.`order_item_id`,`order_item`.`quantity`),0)) + IFNULL(`order_item`.`sales_tax`,0)) + IFNULL(`getshipping_charge_function`(`order_item`.`order_item_id`,`order_item`.`quantity`),0)),2),0)),0) AS `cod`,
  ROUND(SUM(IF((`payment_type`.`a_name` = 'Prepaid'),ROUND((((((`order_item`.`quantity` * `order_item`.`a_unitprice`) - IFNULL(ABS(`getdisc_function`(`order_item`.`order_item_id`,`order_item`.`quantity`)),0)) + IFNULL(`getgiftwrap_amount_function`(`order_item`.`order_item_id`,`order_item`.`quantity`),0)) + IFNULL(`order_item`.`sales_tax`,0)) + IFNULL(`getshipping_charge_function`(`order_item`.`order_item_id`,`order_item`.`quantity`),0)),2),0)),0) AS `Prepaid`,
  ROUND((SUM(IF((`payment_type`.`a_name` = 'COD'),ROUND((((((`order_item`.`quantity` * `order_item`.`a_unitprice`) - IFNULL(ABS(`getdisc_function`(`order_item`.`order_item_id`,`order_item`.`quantity`)),0)) + IFNULL(`getgiftwrap_amount_function`(`order_item`.`order_item_id`,`order_item`.`quantity`),0)) + IFNULL(`order_item`.`sales_tax`,0)) + IFNULL(`getshipping_charge_function`(`order_item`.`order_item_id`,`order_item`.`quantity`),0)),2),0)) + SUM(IF((`payment_type`.`a_name` = 'Prepaid'),ROUND((((((`order_item`.`quantity` * `order_item`.`a_unitprice`) - IFNULL(ABS(`getdisc_function`(`order_item`.`order_item_id`,`order_item`.`quantity`)),0)) + IFNULL(`getgiftwrap_amount_function`(`order_item`.`order_item_id`,`order_item`.`quantity`),0)) + IFNULL(`order_item`.`sales_tax`,0)) + IFNULL(`getshipping_charge_function`(`order_item`.`order_item_id`,`order_item`.`quantity`),0)),2),0))),0) AS `grandtotal`,
  ROUND((ROUND((SUM(IF((`payment_type`.`a_name` = 'COD'),ROUND((((((`order_item`.`quantity` * `order_item`.`a_unitprice`) - IFNULL(ABS(`getdisc_function`(`order_item`.`order_item_id`,`order_item`.`quantity`)),0)) + IFNULL(`getgiftwrap_amount_function`(`order_item`.`order_item_id`,`order_item`.`quantity`),0)) + IFNULL(`order_item`.`sales_tax`,0)) + IFNULL(`getshipping_charge_function`(`order_item`.`order_item_id`,`order_item`.`quantity`),0)),2),0)) + SUM(IF((`payment_type`.`a_name` = 'Prepaid'),ROUND((((((`order_item`.`quantity` * `order_item`.`a_unitprice`) - IFNULL(ABS(`getdisc_function`(`order_item`.`order_item_id`,`order_item`.`quantity`)),0)) + IFNULL(`getgiftwrap_amount_function`(`order_item`.`order_item_id`,`order_item`.`quantity`),0)) + IFNULL(`order_item`.`sales_tax`,0)) + IFNULL(`getshipping_charge_function`(`order_item`.`order_item_id`,`order_item`.`quantity`),0)),2),0))),0) / COUNT(DISTINCT `orders`.`order_id`)),0) AS `avgtickectsize`,
  ROUND((ROUND((SUM(IF((`payment_type`.`a_name` = 'COD'),ROUND((((((`order_item`.`quantity` * `order_item`.`a_unitprice`) - IFNULL(ABS(`getdisc_function`(`order_item`.`order_item_id`,`order_item`.`quantity`)),0)) + IFNULL(`getgiftwrap_amount_function`(`order_item`.`order_item_id`,`order_item`.`quantity`),0)) + IFNULL(`order_item`.`sales_tax`,0)) + IFNULL(`getshipping_charge_function`(`order_item`.`order_item_id`,`order_item`.`quantity`),0)),2),0)) + SUM(IF((`payment_type`.`a_name` = 'Prepaid'),ROUND((((((`order_item`.`quantity` * `order_item`.`a_unitprice`) - IFNULL(ABS(`getdisc_function`(`order_item`.`order_item_id`,`order_item`.`quantity`)),0)) + IFNULL(`getgiftwrap_amount_function`(`order_item`.`order_item_id`,`order_item`.`quantity`),0)) + IFNULL(`order_item`.`sales_tax`,0)) + IFNULL(`getshipping_charge_function`(`order_item`.`order_item_id`,`order_item`.`quantity`),0)),2),0))),0) / SUM(`order_item`.`quantity`)),0) AS `avgitemprice`,
  ROUND((SUM(`order_item`.`quantity`) / COUNT(DISTINCT `orders`.`order_id`)),0) AS `avgitemperorder`,
  COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE `status`.`status_code` WHEN 'S' THEN `orders`.`order_id` WHEN 'DE' THEN `orders`.`order_id` END)) AS `dispached`,
  (COUNT(DISTINCT `orders`.`order_id`) - COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE `status`.`status_code` WHEN 'S' THEN `orders`.`order_id` WHEN 'DE' THEN `orders`.`order_id` END))) AS `notdispached`
FROM (((((`orders`
       JOIN `order_item`
         ON ((`order_item`.`order_id` = `orders`.`order_id`)))
      JOIN `payment_instruction`
        ON ((`payment_instruction`.`order_id` = `orders`.`order_id`)))
     JOIN `subpayment_type`
       ON ((`payment_instruction`.`payment_method` = `subpayment_type`.`subpayment_type_id`)))
    JOIN `payment_type`
      ON (((`payment_type`.`payment_type_id` = `subpayment_type`.`payment_type_id`)
           AND (`payment_type`.`a_name` = ('Prepaid'
                                             OR 'COD')))))
   LEFT JOIN `status`
     ON ((`status`.`a_statusid` = `orders`.`orderstatus_id`)))
WHERE (`status`.`status_code` NOT IN('PP','PE','X'))
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`orders`.`placed_date`,'%y-%m%-%d')
```

Comment: Pl post your query and explain...

Comment: @Meherzad - check now.

Comment: Please add also result of EXPLAIN statement: `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` so that we know which indexes MySQL is using and how many rows it needs to process

Answer (score 0):

Views in MySQL can be slow. There is an article about this problem - [MySQL VIEW as performance troublemaker](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/08/12/mysql-view-as-performance-troublemaker/).

If it is possible - use simple SELECT queries without views.

Answer (score 0):

Having only query (without DDL, number of rows etc.) it's rather guessing.

You can try adding indexes on columns which you use to join tables and in `WHERE` clause. It has sense especially if there are many rows in these tables.

Also try to recognize the slowest part of this statement. Maybe it's JOIN, maybe these calculations in SELECT list? You can cut off one part and see wheter it will be fast without it. Then you should focus on this slowest part.

Comment: I already did it. If i remove all calculations and put * instead of it it comes very very fast. Calculations are main thing here and here its repeated calculations. If i do calculations once and store in some variable it can be helpful. But not able to do it.